# javascript array if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make an array for the days of the week but i want it to display an error if the number entered is not assigned to a value. this is what i have but it says "today is undefined" after my if statement. i think it's because of the array. is there a way to put the if statement as part of the array so only one message pops up?

```js
var dayNum=prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' ');
if (dayNum >='7');
{
alert("invalid input received, try again")
} 
var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", " "];
alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the semicolon here is terminating the statement

```
if (dayNum >='7');
```

Remove the semicolon.  Also, if the input is invalid, your second case is still running.  Instead place that into an else statement.

```js
var dayNum = Number( prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' ') );
if ( isNaN(dayNum) || dayNum >= 7 )
{
  alert("invalid input received, try again")
} else {
  var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);
}
```

Finally, it's also wise to convert strings (which is the return type of prompt) to a number type before treating them as one. In this case, JavaScript knows the index of an array can only be a number and will therefore automatically attempt to convert the type for you.  As long as the user types a valid number, it can be used as the index without a problem.  However, strings are compared alphabetically.  Which means that `(string >= '7')` might not always behave the way you expect: Letters are greater than numbers, but special characters are less.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `;` after  `if (dayNum >=7)`

```js
var dayNum=prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' ');


if (dayNum >=7)
{
alert("invalid input received, try again")
} 
var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", " "];
alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = weekdays[dayNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors in your code. First is the semicolon after if condition and the other one is using string comparison instead of numeric. Remove the quote from digit in the if condition. And also the index for array is wrong. You are providing a string. It should be int type.

```
<script>
var dayNum=parseInt(prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' '));
if (dayNum >= 7)
{
alert("invalid input received, try again");

} 
else{
var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", " "];
alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);

}
</script>
```

Comment: and also you need to use the else statement otherwise the second part will also get executed and you will get alert saying today is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will want to have the input be 1-7 and have a fake error to be declared if you use 0 for example:

```
var weekdays = ["Error", "Sun", "Mon", ..., "Sat"];
```

Then you will want to make a loop to convert the string into a number:

```
for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
   if(dayNum==i){
      dayNum=i;
   }
}
```

That will give you a integer rather than a string, using approximate values. Your fished code will look like:

```js
var dayNum=prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' ');
for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
    if(dayNum==i){
        dayNum=i;
    }
}
if (dayNum <=7)
{
    alert("invalid input received, try again");
}
else if(dayNum === 0)
{
    alert("invalid input received, try again");
}
else
{
var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", " "];
alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dayNum=prompt('enter as number from 0 to 6', ' ');
for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
    if(dayNum==i){
        dayNum=i;
    }
}
if (dayNum >=7)
{
    alert("invalid input received, try again");
}
else if(dayNum === 0)
{
    alert("invalid input received, try again");
}
else
{
var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", " "];
alert("Today is " + weekdays[dayNum]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.